# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')

Tags: javascript, typeerror

not quite sure why I'm getting an error in the console, the game is working correctly and I have fiddled around for hours trying to find a solution. I have a few error codes, the first one is script.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')
at randomSquare (script.js:28:17) and the second error code is :
script.js:80 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')
at countDown (script.js:80:24)
I think this could be due to having an animation of the game on my homepage but when I removed it, the error codes still appear. I'm fairly new to coding and completely lost right now, any help appreciated, thanks

```
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
const mole = document.querySelector('.mole-image');
const timeLeft = document.querySelector('#time-left');
const scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#score');
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor-mallet img");

let molePosition;
let score = 0;
let currentTime = 20;
let timerId = null;


let successfulWhack = () => new Audio("assets/audio/hit-sound.flac").play();
let playSound = () => new Audio("assets/audio/hammer-whack.wav").play();
let audio = document.getElementById('audio');
let playPauseBtn = document.getElementById('playPauseBtn');
let count = 0;


function randomSquare() {
squares.forEach(square => {
  square.classList.remove('mole-image');
});

let randomSquare = squares[Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)];
   randomSquare.classList.add('mole-image');


   molePosition = randomSquare.id;
}
  squares.forEach(square => {
  square.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  if (square.id == molePosition) {
    successfulWhack();
    score++;
    scoreDisplay.textContent = score;
    molePosition = null;
  }
});
});

function moveMole() {
 moleTimerId = setInterval(randomSquare, 800);
}

moveMole();

function countDown() {
  currentTime--;
  timeLeft.textContent = currentTime;
  
if (currentTime ==  0) {
    clearInterval(countDownTimerId);
    clearInterval(moleTimerId);
    window.alert('GAME OVER! Your final score is ' + score);
    location.reload();
    playSound();
    }
  }
let countDownTimerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
```

Comment: The error means that at the time your script tries to access `xyz.classList` the `xyz` part is undefined.

Comment: okay thanks, still slightly confused as the xyz.classList has been defined above? as let randomSquare. sorry if this sounds like a stupid response.

Comment: What you can do to reduce the chance of an error is to use `squares.length` instead of a hardcoded `12`. Also a typical reason why vars that are supposed to point to elements are empty is that the script is above the respective elements and therefore querySelector(All) doesn't find anything

Comment: Agree with @ChrisG, your `const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square')` is not finding any matching elements in the DOM (try using the debugger in the browser or a `console.log(squares)` after that line to prove it). If after checking your HTML you think those elements should be in the DOM, then the suggestion of checking when this script executes is a sound one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the randomSquare variable does not have a classList property.
It looks like timeLeft is null.

You should be able to validate this by logging the values of each before you call them. For example, you can put this logging in place:

```
// in randomSquare()
let randomSquare = squares[Math.floor(Math.random() * 12)];
console.log('randomSquare: ' + JSON.stringify(randomSquare));
console.log('randomSquare.classList: ' + JSON.stringify(randomSquare.classList));

// in countDown()
currentTime--;
console.log('timeLeft: ' + JSON.stringify(timeLeft));

// This will probably throw an error and not print
console.log('timeLeft.textContent: ' + JSON.stringify(timeLeft.textContent));
```

edit: Try logging with and without JSON.stringify.

I would also change the randomSquare variable inside the function randomSquare() to be any different name so that you know you're not calling the function when you mean to be calling the variable.

Comment: I have resolved one of the issues by using the above squares.length instead of the hardcoded 12. I have tried to use the above with JSON.stringify but not much seems to be happening. I have changed the name randomSquare variable inside the function to prevent calling the function. The error is now  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')  at countDown (script.js:52:26)  - timeRemain.textContent = currentTime; I have tried to change this to inner.HTML but doesn't seem to do much

Comment: @chris-t93 I did put JSON.stringify because that helps a lot with Javascript objects. I didn't realize that when logging HTML elements it is probably more helpful to just log the element itself.

I think the current error that you're getting is because timeRemain is null. You can reproduce the error by putting this in any Javascript console (Open the dev console in chrome and paste it):
document.getElementById("not_a_real_element").textContent = "hello"

The error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent')"

Comment: @chris-t93 Changing it to .innerHTML is completely pointless because it's not the .textContent part that's the problem, it's the timeRemain part. Reread the error message and pay attention to the exact wording: Cannot read properties **of** `undefined` (reading 'textContent') (see also my very first comment up top)